# Azure global network firewall

Tags: azure, security, networking, azure-web-app-service

I've got several Subscriptions in a Tenant. I'm trying to find a way to avoid new Web Apps to be accessible for the open internet.

I could create a Network Security Group for that application and control the access from there. But I was thinking for something more... "global". Tenancy level or subscription lever if the global is not possible.

Can something like that be set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to highlight, VNet Integration gives your web app access to resources in your virtual network but does not grant private access to your web app from the virtual network. Private site access refers to making your app only accessible from a private network such as from within an Azure virtual network. Private site access is only available with an ASE configured with an Internal Load Balancer (ILB). For details on using an ILB ASE, start with the article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase

A common scenario where you would use VNet Integration is enabling access from your web app to a database or a web service running on a virtual machine in your Azure virtual network. With VNet Integration, you don't need to expose a public endpoint for applications on your VM but can use the private non-internet routable addresses instead.
Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: oh, yeah, good catch, you can use ASE, if you are rich enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Network Security Groups can only be applied to subnet level (not even vnet), you can apply to NIC but that even lower
2. NSG do not work for WebApps
3. For WebApps you need to use web.config to control access
4. Pretty sure there is no way of doing what you want to achieve in a centralized fashion at least out of the box in Azure

Comment: I was thinking of having a VM with a public IP that would work as a proxy to the Web App(s), I thought you would be able to filter connections that way... But then again, that's not really what I'm looking for

Comment: well, you can probably invent many ways to do this, but OUT OF THE BOX, there are none.